# When running the following code, why does it run 6 times?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to run this code so that if the statements are true, then a toastMessage should appear but for some reason, it is trying to run the toast 6 times, according to the logs.

When the toast run, it flashes each time it is run. How can I let the toast only run once?

Even If I replace the toast with an alert, I have to press OK 6 times before it will dismiss.

**Log Result:**

```
checkForIOSRequests/riderId: xmmEHZJkOXOJbLXdCQjuZvpS80j1
checkForIOSRequests/riderId: xmmEHZJkOXOJbLXdCQjuZvpS80j1
checkForIOSRequests/riderId: xmmEHZJkOXOJbLXdCQjuZvpS80j1
checkForIOSRequests/riderId: xmmEHZJkOXOJbLXdCQjuZvpS80j1
checkForIOSRequests/riderId: xmmEHZJkOXOJbLXdCQjuZvpS80j1
checkForIOSRequests/riderId: xmmEHZJkOXOJbLXdCQjuZvpS80j1
requestToastMessage
requestToastMessage
requestToastMessage
requestToastMessage
requestToastMessage
requestToastMessage
```

**checkForIOSRequests**

```
iosRequests.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                riderId = ds.getKey();
                Log.e(TAG, "checkForIOSRequests/riderId: " + riderId);

                iosRequests.child(riderId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue() != null) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.child("isIOSRider").getValue() != null) {
                                String isIOSRider = (String) dataSnapshot.child("isIOSRider").getValue();
                                String onlineStatus = (String) dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue();
                                if (isIOSRider.equals("true") && onlineStatus.equals("requested")) {
                                    requestToastMessage();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
```

**EDIT**

```
DatabaseReferene rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference iosRequests = rootRef.child("RideRequests");
```

[image: firebase screenshot]

[image: RideRequests]

**EDIT 2**

When I run the following code, it runs it 6 times like in the **Log Result**

```
iosRequests.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                riderId = ds.getKey();

                iosRequests.child(riderId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        int size = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                        Log.e(TAG, "children count = " + size);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**Log Result**

[image: Log Result image]

Comment: How many children does the `ds` object have?

Comment: @AlexMamo The children count is 15.  See the newly added RideRequests node image in EDIT part of post.

Comment: When running the code I have (see in EDIT 2), it runs the code 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

I just don't know why are you using two database call when you can do filter using one database query.

Just use below query to filter out all IOSRider using `isIOSRider` key.

```
DatabaseReferene rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference iosRequests = rootRef.child("RideRequests");

Query queryIOSRiders = iosRequests.orderByChild("isIOSRider").equalTo(true);
// Keep in mind that, if you are storing boolean value in database then only use true in equalTo(...). i.e. equalTo(true)
// Else use true covered with quotes. i.e. equalTo("true")
```

And make call of database,

```
queryIOSRiders. addListenerForSingleValueEvent(...)
```

This query returns all iOS riders list, so then after you need to put simple if-else braces to filter out suitable riders.

For example, your final result handling code should be like,

```
queryIOSRiders.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if(dataSnapshot.getValue()!= null) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             if (ds.child("status").getValue() != null) {
                 String onlineStatus = (String) ds.child("status").getValue();
                 if (onlineStatus.equals("requested")) {
                     requestToastMessage();
                 }
             }
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
});
```

Comment: I tried doing as you suggested but nothing happened.  Changed the addListenerForSingleValueEvent to addValueEventListener and it did what it was supposed to do but it ran requestToastMessage 4x.  Also, don't I. need to get the riderId first?

Comment: Also, if I continue with accepting the request, the toast continues when I go to another activity, adding the runs of requestToastMessage to be doubled.